# Kotlin сортировка ArrayList

Tags: kotlin

Мне необходимо отсортировать ArrayList по двум параметрам. Это делаю так

```
val files = fileManager.getFiles().sortedWith(compareBy<File> { it.isFile }.thenBy {
            it.name.toLowerCase(
                Locale.ROOT) })
```

Теперь мне нужно в определенных ситуациях вставить в начале списка 1 элемент.

Но так я использовал sortedWith и thenBy, то результатом является List, который нельзя редактировать (у него метода add).

Есть варианты как обойти эту проблему, не проходять по List и не занося все в ArrayList?

Comment: retrun listOf(addedToFirstPosition) + files

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в конце toMutableList()

```
val files = fileManager.getFiles().sortedWith(compareBy<File> { it.isFile }.thenBy {
            it.name.toLowerCase(
                Locale.ROOT) }).toMutableList()
```

[Методы](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/) MutableList